# Activity closing unexpectedly after pressing back button

Tags: android-activity, countdowntimer

I'm currently trying to diagnosis a bug where when a user is wanting to back out of the game activity using the back button it closes the window but doesn't seem to actually close the activity. The reason I think the activity isn't closing is because when a new game activity is started, the activity seems to call onFinish from CountDownTimer and close as if the time ran out when the timer in game shows there is still time left in the new game. Essentially I think my old activity is closing my new activity, even after the activity is no longer showing and should be closed based on my onBackPressed() method.

Here is my code:

```
public class Game extends Activity {
ImageButton position0;
ImageButton position1;
ImageButton position2;
ImageButton position3;
Button colorPosition;
RelativeLayout background;
Random rand = new Random();
int[] position = {0,1,2,3};
int score = 0;
int streak = 1;
int multi = 1;
int currentColor;
SharedPreferences gamePrefs;
boolean countDisable = true;
public static final String GAME_PREFS = "ColorMatchFile";
TextView scoreText;
TextView multiplierText;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    gamePrefs = getSharedPreferences(GAME_PREFS, 0);
    scoreText =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    multiplierText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.multiplier);
    background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
    StartCount start_count = new StartCount(5000, 1000);
    start_count.start();
    colorPosition = (Button)findViewById(R.id.colorPosition);
    position0 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.position0);
    position1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.position1);
    position2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.position2);
    position3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.position3);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        int exScore = savedInstanceState.getInt("score");
        scoreText.setText("Score: "+ exScore);
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setHighScore();
    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), score_screen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture,long countDownInterval){
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setText("Times Up!");
        Thread thread = new Thread();
        try {
            thread.sleep(250);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setHighScore();
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), score_screen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
        final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished/1000);
    }
}

    public class StartCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public StartCount(long millisInFuture,long countDownInterval){
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setText("Begin!");
        MyCount counter = new MyCount(30000, 1000);
        currentColor = rand.nextInt(4);
        setCurrentColor(currentColor);
        countDisable = false;
        counter.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
        final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setText("Start In: " + millisUntilFinished/1000);
        showCurrentPosition();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post more code. Where is MyCount used? Whats the gamecontext?

Comment: Any error appeared in LogCat?

Comment: No, that's the weird thing about it. LogCat doesn't see it as an error because I am pressing the back button instead of letting the activity close using MyCount.onFinish(). When onFinish() is used (the time runs out completely) everything acts normally. The issue is when the user closes the activity mid game.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem was I wasn't turning the counter for MyCount off. Here is how I solved it:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setHighScore();
    counter.cancel();
    this.finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), score_screen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Note I had to use counter.cancel() and make counter a global variable.